c# ms sql | Ошибка соединения с SQL Server
я написал приложение на c# wpf с системой авторизации, использующей подключение к MS SQL базе данных. База данных находится на хостинге с поддержкой ms sql (1gb.ru если кому то надо).
Я начал тестировать приложение, на моём ПК при подключении и авторизации ошибок никаких нет, у некоторых людей на других ПК тоже ошибок нет и всё норм, но есть человек, у которого при нажатии на кнопку "Зарегистрироваться" или "Войти" приложение зависает и выдаёт ошибку:
При установлении соединения с SQL Server произошла ошибка,
связанная с сетью или с определенным экземпляром. Сервер не найден
или недоступен. Убедитесь, что имя экземпляра указано правильно и
что на SQL Server разрешены удалённые соединения. (provider: Named
Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Не удалось открыть подключение к SQL Server)

Строка подключения:
SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=ms.sql.10.in.solve.ru;Initial Catalog=1gb_users;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=*Логин*;Password=*Пароль*");

При нажатии на кнопки используются методы C# (SqlDataAdapter, DataTable, SqlCommand)
Буду очень благодарен если поможете разобраться с ошибкой, если нужна ещё информация, могу дать.

добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками. (насколько смог разглядеть, на картинке у вас как раз причина и написана).

aleksandr, исправил

Не стоит гадать, нужно подключиться удаленно на комп, где воспроизводится ошибка и начать отладку/диагностику там. Возможно, закрыт порт, не пускает файрволл/прокси-сервер, нет доступа к ДНС и тд.
